# Error in check --as-cran "there is no package called ..."

Tags: r, package, cran

I have a revision of a package in which I have added some plotting code that uses the **ggplot2** package as well as a custom scale from the package **scales**. In particular, the new code has one line that references the **scales** package, of the form:

```
trans = scales::trans_new("new scale", ...)
```

I sent the package to Winbuilder to check it and I get this error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'scales'
```

... and indeed I get the same error if I run `R CMD check --as-cran`

- Yes, **scales** is installed on my system.
- Yes, **scales** is included in `Suggests` in my `DESCRIPTION` file; I
  have double- and triple-checked this.
- Yes, **scales** appears to be a package still available on CRAN, with lots and lots of reverse dependencies.

I also have dozens of calls to `ggplot2::xxxx` routines in my code, and **ggplot2** is also in `Suggests`. No errors there.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: ggplot2 is not in Depends, and I use `ggplot2::` a bunch of times in the same way. I definitely do not want extra stuff in Depends.

Comment: If you have dozens of calls to something then your package clearly depends on it. What would happen to your users when they hit those references?

Comment: I have a `requireNamespace()` check accompanying them. I figured it out. See my answer...

Comment: @Elin Thinking about this further, I'd say that one shouldn't put anything in Depends unless the user really needs that package in the search path. For packages needed to accomplish the central purposes of a package, those should go in Imports. In this case, users of my package may never use any of its plotting capabilities, so I put **ggplot2** in Suggests and do the namespace check. I think excessive dependencies is a real issue with R packages. Many have hundreds of dependencies, and that's all stuff that needs to be loaded into memory.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out; it was a bit subtle (at least for somebody like me).

In the other places in my package where I call functions from a package in `Suggests`, I also have a line of code that looks like this:

```
if (!requireNamespace("ggplot2", quietly = TRUE))
    stop ("The 'ggplot2' package is not installed installed.", call. = FALSE)
... code that calls ggplot2:: functions
```

The problem here was that (a) I didn't have such a check for `scales`; but more important, (b) the assignment above, `trans = scales::...` was in the namespace of my package.

So what I did was move the assignment of `trans` to the interior of the function where it is used, and preceded it with a `requireNamespace()` test similar to the above. Now my package check at least passes that point in the `--as-cran` check.